# Download a specific folder from on-prem GitLab

Tags: linux, bash, git, jenkins, gitlab

I have an on-prem GitLab with a huge repository with many folders.

I'm trying to create a freestyle Jenkins job that would only retrieve the folder from the repository. (I have a read-permitted API token)

With Jenkins or a bash script, is it possible to retrieve only a specific folder from an on-prem GitLab installation?

I've tried many things from online suggestions but nothing worked.

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1):

I solved such kind of issue as follow:

```sh
   git clone --no-checkout --depth=1 <REPO_URI> repo.local \
&& cd repo.local \
&& git checkout <REPO_BRANCH> <REPO_FOLDER>/*
```

In other words:

1. You clone only the latest repo layer.
2. You checkout only the folder you need.

Comment: Thanks for the response! May I ask what's going on in the clone stage with these flags? Does it only copy the latest changes?

Comment: As I wrote at **step 1** it does not clone the whole project history, but only the most recent files image, wuthout checking them out. The `git checkout` then extract only the folder you need.